# Snapshot debugging resource not found in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a storage account and an app insight which were linked for snapshot debugging purposes.

I have a C# OData service in which is using application insight with NLog. The service itself is supposed to run in an AKS clusters, but for testing purposes of the question, I'm trying to use the snapshot debugger on a cluster which runs locally.

First question:  Can snapshot debugging can even be used with services which are created as images and are deployed to an AKS cluster?

Second, I tried enabling the snapshot debugging by doing the following steps:

Adding the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector package (version 1.4.4)

In startup.cs file added these lines:

```
services.AddSnapshotCollector();
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();  
services.AddSingleton<TelemetryClient>();
```

In my ODataQueryProcessor I did this:

```
    var telemetryClient = query.Request.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<TelemetryClient>();
    
    try
    {
        throw new ForbiddenOperationException("Test Exception");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Logging.Trace("TRACKING TEST EXCEPTION");
        telemetryClient.TrackException(e);
    }
```

The exception is always being thrown on purpose so I can track it.

After I ran the code, I tried attaching the snapshot debugger by Debug => Attach snapshot debugger.

When selecting my Azure subscription, I got a message saying "There are no existing instances available". I'm not sure what resources does it look for - is it for the storage account? because it is there in the subscription. If it looks for a cluster, I'm trying to use it on a local cluster as I was saying before so it won't find it - if that's the case, can I use snapshot debugging with a local cluster?

Comment: What is the Visual studio version you are using?

Comment: @Harshitha 2022 Enterprise. I know you said its something related to 2019 but the docs said its 2019 and above

Comment: I have tried to enable the snapshot debugger option in Vs 2022 but as I said unable to find the option.

Comment: Will explore and let you know.

Comment: And what is the application framework and version you are using ?

Comment: There's a need to add the snapshot debugging option by installing the Azure development workload in the VS components. There's a specific snapshot debugging option there to install. And thank you

Comment: by application framework do you mean .net 6?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253757/discussion-between-harshitha-and-yonatan-nir).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a WebApp in VS 2022 Enterprise edition.

Check the below workaround to continue using Snapshot Debugger.

I have tried to `Attach the Debugger`.
Even I got the same message.

[image]

- And for other subscriptions Iam unable to find all the `resource groups`.
- I tried to check in the Azure Portal, When I see the subscription which I have selected above I didn't see any resources available.

[image]

- Make sure your app is deployed correctly and AKS cluster created in the Azure Portal.
- If we don't have `AKS`in the selected `Resource Group` / `Subscription`, we will get this error.

> ```cs
> "There are no existing instances available".
> ```

- Make sure you have logged in to the Visual Studio Account with the same Azure Account where you have subscription.
- Either deploy the App from Visual Studio or Create a new AKS in Azure Portal, then you can see the resources.
- I have created AKS Cluster from portal.

[image]

- Now Iam able to see the instances.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What I'm using it for is for an OData service hosted inside Azure AKS cluster. How does it change the answer from a web app?

Comment: Checking.. Just give me sometime.

Comment: Sure.. sorry if you felt like I'm putting any pressure on you as its of course wasn't my intention

Comment: Sorry my bad,instead of AKS I mentioned Azure App.Will updated the answer.

Comment: OK. It could have been nice to just create a resource for a service in aks as well like for an app

Comment: Working on it will update soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253766/discussion-between-harshitha-and-yonatan-nir).

Comment: Do you might know how to answer this one: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383539/azure-profiler-session-does-not-appear-in-app-insight