# Is snapshot debugging supported for services hosted in an AKS cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I got some conflicting information between the official docs and some answers I've seen here in other questions.

I want to use snapshot debugging with a service which is hosted as an image created from a Docker file (referenced by a helm chart image) inside an AKS cluster.

The [official MS Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/snapshot-debugger/snapshot-debugger#environments) doesn't state a service hosted in an AKS cluster as a supported environment. I also did not succeed in using snapshot debugging yet and I'm afraid I'm wasting my time trying. However, some answers mentioned it can be done as long as the snapshot debugger connects to the AKS cluster which will be defined as an Azure resource.

So what is true here? Is snapshot debugging supported for services hosted inside an AKS cluster?

Answer (score 0):

For services hosted within an AKS cluster, snapshot debugging is available. Snapshot debugging can be used to debug .NET applications running in AKS.

Detailed steps for using snap shot debugging within an AKS cluster is clearly given in this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-to-debug-your-live-aks-app-with-snapshot-debugger/#:%7E:text=Snapshot%20Debugging%20is%20now%20supported%20in%20Azure%20Kubernetes,Virtual%20Machines%20and%20Azure%20Virtual%20Machine%20scale%20sets.) by @Mark Downie.

To use it in the application:

1. Install the snapshot debugger extension for visual studio.
2. Add it to your application and deploy it to AKS.

To connect the snapshot debugger extension to your AKS cluster, you can add it in the code in below manner.

```
{  "name":  "DebuggerConnectionString",  
   "value": xxxxx
},
{  "name":  xxxx
    "value": xxxxx
}
    ....
```

But if you want to debug services hosted within an AKS cluster, I suggest you refer into additional debugging Kubernetes environments like Kubernetes-specific logging too.

Comment: Besides adding the extension don't I need to do other stuff as well like adding lines of code to the startup class and also log an exception using the telemetry client to track an exception? The blog seems lacking but I'm not sure? Is it possible if you could comment on another question of mine just to ensure I setup everything correctly or if I might have done something which is not needed? This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76299886/snapshot-debugging-resource-not-found-in-azure

Comment: Also, what if my AKS cluster is behind a private network?

Comment: It means did you add any firewall functionality for your cluster?

Comment: It's behind Azure Front door

Comment: Do you might know how to answer this one: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383539/azure-profiler-session-does-not-appear-in-app-insight